# UIControl Callback in GUI matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a following GUI program to run another gui figure in matlab 2014b.

```
% --- Executes on button press in Spectrometer
function Spectrometer_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Spectrometer (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
data = getappdata(gcbf, 'labdata');
% open Spectrometer only if it is not already open
if ~isfield(data,'hSpectrometer')
    data.hSpectrometer=SpectrometerGui('handle',num2str(gcbf,16));
elseif ~ishandle(str2double(data.hSpectrometer)) 
data.hSpectrometer=SpectrometerGui('handle',num2str(gcbf,16));
end
setappdata(gcbf, 'labdata', data);
```

The following error appears every time. Any idea what is the reason for getting error?

```
 Undefined function 'real' for input arguments of type 'matlab.ui.Figure'.

 Error in num2str (line 132)
        raw = cellPrintf(f, real(x), false);

Error in horus>Spectrometer_Callback (line 997)
    data.hSpectrometer=SpectrometerGui('handle',num2str(gcbf,16));

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in lab (line 46)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in   @(hObject,eventdata)lab('Spectrometer_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))  



Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Comment: Which version of MATLAB are you using, and what does `gcbf` return?  Your code is assuming that it is a number, so put a breakpoint within your callback and step through the lines of code to verify that this is the case.

Comment: Starting with R2014b, graphics handles are now objects instead of numerical pointers so the approach you're trying to use will not work. @Geoff R2014b is in the first sentence of his question.

Comment: See the new [`Number`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#prop_Number) property as a workaround to keep existing functionality.

Comment: @excaza is right.  Read [this article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2014/11/05/matlab-r2014b-graphics-part-3-compatibility-considerations-in-the-new-graphics-system/#eed4c37f-5539-4ebb-b5e3-eb41e880b752) to understand more in detail. As a temporary workaround, Loren explain: "_It is possible to cast object handles to numeric handles using the `double` function. You can then cast the number back to an object handle using the `handle` function. We don't recommend this as a long term solution._"